# POST params to a stubbed rack app with rspec and webmock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Using Rails 4.2.3, Rspec 3

I want to pass post params to a fake Rack app to respond accordingly in my tests.

My Fake app:

```rb
# spec/support/fake_mangopay.rb
class FakeMangopay < Sinatra::Base
  attr_accessor :user

  post '/:version/oauth/token' do
    json_response :post, 200, 'token.json'
  end

...

  private

  def json_response(method, response_code, file_name)
    content_type :json
    status response_code
    File.open("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/fixtures/mangopay/#{method}/#{file_name}", 'rb').read
  end
end
```

How I stub the requests:

```rb
# spec/spec_helper
config.before(:each) do
  stub_request(:any, /api.sandbox.mangopay.com/).to_rack(FakeMangopay)
  ...
end
```

I currently have simple (and static) JSON files, and I would like to make them json.erb files.
But I don't know how to get those post parameters..

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that I can access `request.body` to get what I want.

```rb
params = JSON.parse request.body.read
```